# In my test script I get my if statment run but I never get the else to run? What I am doing wrong

Tags: javascript, html

If you run this script and enter 2 in the prompt box it never runs the else and I do not know why. Is it how I set the var or myFunction that is incorrect.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to demonstrate the prompt box.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{
var x=1;
var name=prompt("Please enter a number one");

if ( x===1)
  {
alert("good");
  }
else 
  {
alert("not a number 1");
  }

} 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe you want to check `x == name`.

You're checking `x === 1` which is always true because you've set `x = 1` and never overwritten it.

Additionally, `x === name` won't work as `prompt` returns a string, and `1` is a number. You may want to set `x = '1'` and then check `x === name` if you're going to use strict comparison.

Comment: Correct that you for your help

Comment: @user1324518, If this was the answer you were looking for, please remember to select the checkmark under the vote count.

Answer (score 1):

You're never assigning x to anything but 1! Then you check to see that it is indeed integer 1.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are defining `x=1` in your script and then checking `x === 1`.

Perhaps you meant to assign the user input to `x`, but you're not doing that.

Or as zzzzBov says, maybe you meant to do `x === name` or `x == name` depending on your purpose.

Comment: He could always use `parseInt` if he expects the user to enter a number.

Comment: Edited anyways to include both.

Answer (score 0):

Change your script to

```
if (prompt("Please enter a number one") != 1){
    alert('Not a number 1');
} else {
    alert('Good')
}
```